# Получение самого большого числа реферального кода среди пользователей

Tags: python, sql

не могу понять как мне получить максимальное значение реферального кода среди всех пользователей в таблице Users.
Столбец ReferalCode.

Что у меня пока получается:

```
def GenerateReferalCode(self):
    while True:
        ReferalCode = self.cursor.execute('SELECT ReferalCode FROM Users').fetchone()
    return ReferalCode+1
```

Моя конструкция должна быть такая:
Получить максимально значение реферального кода, после прибавит 1 и вернуть значение.
Тесть есть два пользователя:
1 Пользователь - Реферальный код = 123456
2 Пользователь - Реферальный код = 456789
И вот среди этих пользователей нужно найти самое большое значение реф кода.

---

```
def GenerateReferalCode(self):
    with self.connection:
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT max(ReferalCode) FROM Users')
        ReferalCode = self.cursor.fetchone()
    return ReferalCode+1
```

Выводит ошибку

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'sqlite3.Row' and 'int'
```

Comment: SELECT max(ReferalCode) FROM Users

Comment: работает как нужно или нет?

Comment: Нет, ответ отправил ниже.

Comment: ReferalCode = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]